# How do I map and iterate all events in a single test case

Tags: java, list, hashmap

```java
@Test
public void eventsWithOldSchema() {
    // In this activating required version for test by calling a function which has those activation code
    LoadSchema.activateSchema(myMsvCli, "UsageEvent", "event.schema", "3.4.1", LOG);
    //and with that old schema version I am posting an event           
    postEvent(edmFixture);
    // after posting I would be asserting whether it gets posted
}
```

In this I will be having nearly 50 events with several event names and versions I should iterate and do those in a single test case like it should activate the version of the schema and post than assert. And then to the next version.

E.g.: `LoadSchema.activateSchema(myMsvCli, "UsageEvent", "event.schema", "3.4.1", LOG);`
Here I should have different event instead of `UsageEvent`, different schemaname (`event.schema`) and different version (`3.4.1`)

These all I should pass in map or list and should call that method for that particular event name.

Comment: It sounds like you want to employ a parameterized test.  In essence, you define a single test method which, unlike standard unit test methods, has parameters.  Another method provides the arguments for those parameters.   Do a web search for "junit parameterized tests" and you should find some guides on how to implement and use it.

Comment: Thanks for that... I need to three values in map or list and iterate one by one... How could I do that?